# Am I charged with read operations everytime the location is changed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database which holds 100 locations, each with the `lat` and the `lng` correctly set. I have created a method to actually read the data from the database using a callback:

```
public static void readLocations(MyCallback myCallback) {
    locationsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<LocationModel> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                LocationModel locationModel = document.toObject(LocationModel.class);
                locationList.add(locationModel);
            }
            myCallback.onCallback(locationList);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using a `LocationCallback` to track the current position. Using the following code, I'm calling `readLocations()` method inside LocationCallback to do some maths regarding some distances:

```
LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location myLocation : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            currentLocation = myLocation;
            LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());

            readLocations(locationList -> {
                for (LocationModel lm : locationList) {
                    Double lat = lm.getLat();
                    Double lng = lm.getLng();
                    Location location = new Location("");
                    location.setLatitude(lat);
                    location.setLongitude(lng);

                    //Calculations
                 }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

So everytime the current location is changed, I'm calculating the distance between the current location and the locations from database. So calling `readLocations()` method every time the position is changed, it means that I am querying the database every time? With other words, every time the current location is changed, I'm charged with 100 read operations? Or because I already used a `get()` call, will be considered as a single operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are charged for the number of documents read **on the server** every time you call get().  If local persistence is enabled in your client (it is by default), then the documents may come from cache if the documents are also not changed on the server.  Cached document reads are not charged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Doug. So you are actually saying that if the data on the server never changes, when calling `readLocations()` method, I'm getting the data from the cache, right?

Comment: Yes, unless your query result set changes as a result of changing physical location. Documents in that result set that were not previously cached will need to come from the server.

Comment: Thanks you so much, you're always the savior! ;)