# Is Firestore charging us when offline more than 30 minutes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687232/am-i-charged-with-read-operations-everytime-the-location-is-changed), where Doug Stevenson (Firebase engineer) said:

> Cached document reads are not charged.

But I read in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#pricing_overview):

> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

So if I'm going offline, even if I haven't changed any document, am I charged again? So the data that is already cached, isn't consider a cached data after 30 minutes anymore?

Hope someone can help me about this annoying situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the cache can satisfy the reconnected query, then there are still no reads charged for each cached document.  You are still charged a single read for the query itself, even if it returns no new results that are newer than what's in the cache.

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you
>   perform, even if the query returns no results.

Comment: A single read operation won't be a problem but a query that return 100 items to be charged every time a I get offline for more than 30', would have been a problem. But it's reassuring to hear that. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @Doug-Stevenson That's news to me, thanks for sharing! You don't really inform of how the cache affects pricing anywhere, do you?

Comment: @Doug How many reads occur if the query requests for example 100 documents but the cache only contains 80 of those documents requested by the query, 5 new documents were added to firestore that fall into the query and 15 documents no longer fall into the where clause of the query that fell into the query it in it's last run?