# Listening to a query using persistence

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Acording to Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing):

> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get
>   realtime updates when the query results change. When you listen to the
>   results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in
>   the result set  is added or updated. You are also charged for a read
>   when a document is removed from the result set because the document
>   has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not
>   charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
>   example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
>   if you had issued a brand-new query.

But is not clear about the behavior and pricing for one document. If the persistance are ENABLE and the listener is disconnected than 30 minutes.

So, if I turn on the Listener and the documents are not chagend, I will charged again with the pricing of the [minimum charge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002397/is-firestore-charging-us-when-offline-more-than-30-minutes) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, if I turn on the Listener and the document are not chagend, I will charged again with the pricing of the minimum charge ?

If the offline persistence is enabled (which is by default in Firestore) and the document is not changed, the read operation will be performed from the cache. The reads that are coming from cache are **not** charged in any way.

However, if you are disconnected for more than 30 minutes and once you start listening again, a new query is performed, especially to check if some documents in your collection are changed while you were disconnected. For instance, if in your database two documents are changed, you'll be charged with two read operations, if the query return no result (no ducuments are changed), you'll be charged with only one read operation. This is needed for the query itself.