# FirebaseFirestore SnapshotListener not working with lastest data in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a SnapshotListener to listen to a collection and automatically update items on a screen.

The issue is that when I manually delete the documents from that collection using the console, the listener doesn't detect these updates. It continues to work with the cached data, causing the application to stop functioning because that data doesn't actually exist.

Here's the code snippet:

Here I open the listener:

```
db.collection("RoutesProposals").whereEqualTo("idGuide", currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
    if(error != null) {
        Log.w("error", "Listen failed.", error);
        return;
    }
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
        noRoutesAssigned.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value) {
            RouteProposal routeProposalAux = snapshot.toObject(RouteProposal.class);
            routesProposalsIds.add(snapshot.getId());
            routesIds.add(routeProposalAux.getRouteId());
            showNumberOfParticipantsSlashTotal(routeProposalAux.getParticipantsIds().size(), Integer.valueOf(routeProposalAux.getMaxParticipants()));
            showMainImageOfRoutes();
            datesOfRoutes.add(routeProposalAux.getWhichDay());
            db.collection("Routes").document(routeProposalAux.getRouteId()).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Route routeAux = document.toObject(Route.class);
                        routesNames.add(routeAux.getName());
                        listAdapterRoutesGuide.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        noRoutesAssigned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

I currently don't have any collection named "RoutesProposals." However, it still detects that the path exists ("value" exists).

This is what I see in the console:

> D/value: [DocumentSnapshot{key=RoutesProposals/6wNrVshqPKlrnDpe9iBQ, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=true...},

This then followed by the data of the documents that were within the collection before everything was deleted.

I've tried clearing the Firestore cache before opening the listener, but it hasn't worked. I also tried changing this listener to an onCompleteListener with get() to read from the database only once, and it does read the latest data I have. I changed back to the previous listener to listen for real-time updates, and it worked. However, the moment I manually delete something from Firestore, I encounter the same problem again.

Comment: Can you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812964/18265570) thread?

Answer (score 0):

If the `RoutesProposals/6wNrVshqPKlrnDpe9iBQ` was cached and then deleted from the server, your listener will fire twice:

1. once with the data from the cache (which is what you've shown already), and
2. once more without that document.

If no other `RoutesProposals` are left that second time, it'll trigger the `else` block of your code, so you'll want to add some logging there to show you got the correct result:

```
} else {
    Log.d("Listener", "There were no documents in Firestore matching the query");
    list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    noRoutesAssigned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: It fires twice but both times with the data from the cache. Anyway, after a day and a half, it automatically fixed. Now it listen again to the current data from the server. Maybe it was my connection to the internet who was not working properly and so it retrieved only the data from the cache?